# get Size of CustomView in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an usercontrol (CustomView and CustomViewController) holding an UIImageView - Xamarin.IOS project C#.

I am trying to use this customview as usercontrol in another storyboard.

My CustomView (with Image) is rendered properly in the Main storyboard. but i am unable to capture the Width and Height of the customview once it is rendered in my main view. the default size of my custom view is 600*600 which is the size of Generic. when I try to get the size of custom control - it always gives me the default size instead of the rendered size. Is there a way to capture this??

My custom view is

```
public partial class MyCustomViewController : UIViewController
```

I have tried using

```
myCustomImage.Bounds.Width & Height   (or)
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width
```

- but this gives me the default size 600*600

Is there a way to get the imagesize / customview size rendered in my mainstoryboard. I want to get this size in CustomViewController using C#.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots to illustrate your issue?

Comment: Where do you write this code  : myCustomImage.Bounds.Width & Height   (or)
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width ?